# R gWidgets reading, editing and writing data.frame in GUI

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I'm updating a GUI I created to record and track work progress. At the moment, it allows the user to note what's been said in meetings and on what topic, then save that to a dated XML file. These files are saved in folders marked for different projects.

I want to add a function that allows users to update a csv file of completed tasks. The tasks are all set out in the file, the user just has to select a task to label it as done.

The problem I'm having is that when the submit button is hit, the R session returns an error for the write.table function, saying it can't find the data.frame 'task'.

Is there something I'm getting wrong or do I need to use a completlely different method ?

```
OS <- Sys.info()['sysname']

if (OS == "Linux") {
desktop <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
           full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
           ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)


if ("Desktop" %in% desktop)  {

pedantpath <- paste(getwd(), "/Desktop/pedant", sep="")
}


if ("Bureau" %in% desktop) {

pedantpath <- paste(getwd(), "/Bureau/pedant", sep="")
}
}

if (OS == "Windows") {

pedantpath <-  paste(Sys.getenv()["USERPROFILE"], "\\Desktop\\pedant", sep="")
}

library(RGtk2)
library(cairoDevice)
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)

mainwin <- gwindow("Record Master", horizontal = FALSE, visible=TRUE)
1
select.button <- gbutton("Select", container=mainwin, handler = function(h,...) {
selection <- gfile(type = c ("selectdir"))

win <- gwindow("Record Master", horizontal = FALSE, visible=TRUE)

biggestgroup <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE,  anchor=c(0,-1), container=win)
tip <- glabel("Welcome. \nPlease use this form to keep your records.", anchor=c(0,0), container=biggestgroup)
class <- gcombobox(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), editable=TRUE, expand=TRUE, anchor=c(0,-1), container=biggestgroup)

select.button <- gbutton("Select Task", container=biggestgroup, handler = function(h,...) {


tasks <- read.table(paste(selection, "\\task.csv", sep=""), sep=",")
task <- c(1:30)
task <- gcombobox(as.character(task$V1), editable=TRUE, expand=TRUE, anchor=c(0,-1), container=biggestgroup)
taskchoice <- paste(svalue(task), sep="")
task$V2[which(grepl(as.character(taskchoice), task$V1))] = 1
})


biggergroup <- ggroup(horizontal = TRUE, width = 30,expand=TRUE, container=biggestgroup)
group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, height = 400, use.scrollwindow = TRUE, expand = TRUE, container = biggergroup)
group2 <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, height = 400, use.scrollwindow = TRUE, expand = TRUE, container = biggergroup)
group3 <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, use.scrollwindow = TRUE, anchor=c(0,1), expand = TRUE, container = biggestgroup)



# dialogue boxes for the activities

obj.meeting1.label <- gcombobox(c("no_meeting", "research", "purchasing", "progress", "marketing", "accounting", "deployment", "sales"), editable=TRUE, expand=TRUE, container=group)
meeting1 <- gtext(text = "Insert content", height = 150, expand=TRUE, container=group2)


obj.meeting2.label <- gcombobox(c("no_meeting", "research", "purchasing", "progress", "marketing", "accounting", "deployment", "sales"), editable=TRUE, expand=TRUE, container=group)
meeting2 <- gtext("Insert content",  height = 15, expand=TRUE, container=group2)


obj.meeting3.label <- gcombobox(c("no_meeting", "research", "purchasing", "progress", "marketing", "accounting", "deployment", "sales"), editable=TRUE, expand=TRUE, container=group)
meeting3 <- gtext(text = "Insert content", height = 300, expand=TRUE, container=group2)


obj.meeting4.label <- gcombobox(c("no_meeting", "research", "purchasing", "progress", "marketing", "accounting", "deployment", "sales"), editable=TRUE, expand=TRUE, container=group)
meeting4 <- gtext("Insert content", expand=TRUE, container=group2)


obj.meeting5.label <- gcombobox(c("no_meeting", "research", "purchasing", "progress", "marketing", "accounting", "deployment", "sales"), editable=TRUE, expand=TRUE, container=group)


meeting5 <- gtext("Insert content", expand=TRUE, container=group2)

submitbutton <- gbutton("Submit", container=group3, handler = function(h,...) {
starttag1 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting1.label), ">", sep="")
starttag1 <- gsub(" ", "_", starttag1)
endtag1 <- paste("</", svalue(obj.meeting1.label), ">", sep="")
endtag1 <- gsub(" ", "_", endtag1)

starttag2 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting2.label), ">", sep="")
starttag2 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting2.label), ">", sep="")
endtag2 <- paste("</", svalue(obj.meeting2.label), ">", sep="")
endtag2 <- gsub(" ", "_", endtag2)

starttag3 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting3.label), ">", sep="")
starttag3 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting3.label), ">", sep="")
endtag3 <- paste("</", svalue(obj.meeting3.label), ">", sep="")
endtag3 <- gsub(" ", "_", endtag3)

starttag4 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting4.label), ">", sep="")
starttag4 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting4.label), ">", sep="")
endtag4 <- paste("</", svalue(obj.meeting4.label), ">", sep="")
endtag4 <- gsub(" ", "_", endtag4)

starttag5 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting5.label), ">", sep="")
starttag5 <- paste("<", svalue(obj.meeting5.label), ">", sep="")
endtag5 <- paste("</", svalue(obj.meeting5.label), ">", sep="")
endtag5 <- gsub(" ", "_", endtag5)

report <- c("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>",
"<report>", starttag1, svalue(meeting1), endtag1, starttag2, svalue(meeting2), endtag2, starttag3, svalue(meeting3), endtag3, starttag4, svalue(meeting4), endtag4, starttag5, svalue(meeting5), endtag5, "</report>")

OS <- Sys.info()['sysname']

if (OS == "Linux") {
write.table(report, file=paste(selection, "/", Sys.Date(), ".xml", sep=""), sep="\n", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, append=TRUE)

}

if (OS == "Windows") {
write.table(report, file=paste(selection, "\\", Sys.Date(), ".xml", sep=""), sep="\n", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, append=TRUE)
write.table(task, file=paste(selection, "\\task-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep=""), sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, append=FALSE)

write.table(task, file=paste(selection, "\\task",  ".csv", sep=""), sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, append=FALSE)

}

dispose(win)




})

help.button <- gbutton("Help", container=group3, handler = function(h,...) {

confirmDialog("If the file is not being written, edit the write.table function", handler = function(h,...) {


dispose(h$obj)
})

})


})
```

Comment: Looks like a scoping issue. Try defining task using <<- and then it will be visible to other handlers.

Comment: That was exactly it. The dataframe was disappearing until I used <<- and additionally, the change to task neded to be put in as part of the submit button's action